# What is the average daily workload for a GIS.SE moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

In an effort to spur more competitors to join the illustrious PolyGeo in the upcoming moderator election:  What is the (average) expected daily workload of a GIS.SE mod?  Perhaps folks would be more willing to nominate themselves if they have an idea of how much time investment is required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me the workload isn't terribly onerous, I keep GIS.SE open in a browser tab all the time and when I have a long(ish) compile running I scan the newest question list and keep an eye on the moderation queue, most of the issues that are flagged are fairly easy to deal with occasionally we get more complex issues and we have a chat room to discuss those issues (but it isn't used heavily).

The other thing is spotting duplicate questions and taking the time to dig up the (best) duplicate.

All in all I'd say I spend a hour or less on weekdays and sometimes manage to go all day on a weekend day with out logging in at all.

Comment: Thanks Ian, this provides some good insight.

Answer (score 6):

We are fairly lucky we don't see too much spam, Ian mentions most of the relevant points. Likewise having a browser tab open can be useful when working and processing.

The site has good community feedback flagging posts etc. It can get more in-depth when there is a issue (bad comments taken personally) mods can dissolve the issue.

If there a particular user that is being disruptive a ban can be placed.
Other times users want to delete all there answers/ or delete their account - we can do this, but it is a last resort.

Spend around 1 hour through out the weekday and maybe 10-15mins at weekends.
Obliviously we all have our vacations...

Answer (score 4):

iant and Mapperz already gave insight into the amount of time that is necessary to meet the needs of the site. Another thing that might be worth mentioning is that it's no problem to be offline during the weekend since gis.se is particularly quiet during this period as well as during holiday seasons because nobody (ok, almost nobody) is at work/university having problems with GIS ;-)